# Pandas filter anomalies per group by Zscore

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column "group" that can have 50 different values and a column "value" that is numeric.

An example could be:

```
pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','b','c','a','a','b','a','c','c'],'value':[2,123,4,2.3,2.5,127,128,4,0.003]})

group   value
0   a   2.000
1   b   123.000
2   c   4.000
3   a   2.300
4   a   2.500
5   b   127.000
6   a   128.000
7   c   4.000
8   c   0.003
```

I would like to remove from the dataframe the values that are anomalous for their group, for example abs(zscore)>3 or something like that. In the example the value a,128 would be removed because it is anomalous for group a and the value c,0.003 would be removed too. 123 and 127 are normal because their group is "b".

Output should be something like (with a z-score column):

```
group   value
0   a   2.0
1   b   123.0
2   c   4.0
3   a   2.3
4   a   2.5
5   b   127.0
6   c   4.0
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to compute the zscore of each group? Please provide concrete evidence of your desired output.

Comment: I want the zscore for value for each group and then filter records where the zscore is beyond some threshold. Tx.

Comment: A z-score requires a hypothesis test. What would your null hypothesis be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a column for z score, grouped by a particular group:

```
df['z_score'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean())/x.std())
```

Filter the df given your threshold:

```
df[abs(df['z_score']) > 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the absolute z-score within each group

```
df.groupby('group').value.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()).abs()

0    0.504239
1    0.707107
2    0.577350
3    0.499467
4    0.496286
5    0.707107
6    1.499992
7    0.577350
8    1.154701
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Unfortunately, the datasets are so small that the 128 plays a bigger role than you might have thought.  It's z-score is only 1.5.

I suggest for calculating z-scores of a data point relative to the statistical moments of everything else.

Here's a function that does that.  Notice that I need at least 4 points in the group to do this.  If the length of the group is less than 4, I return 0 for the entire group.

```
def _zscore(x):
    if len(x) > 3:
        v = x.values

        m = (v.sum() - v) / (v.size - 1)

        vm = v - m[:, None]
        np.fill_diagonal(vm, 0)

        s = ((vm ** 2).sum(1) / (v.size - 2)) ** .5

        return (v - m) / s
    else:
        return np.zeros_like(x)
```

Now if we `groupby` and `transform`

```
df.groupby('group').value.transform(_zscore)

0     -0.582866
1      0.000000
2      0.000000
3     -0.576658
4     -0.572532
5      0.000000
6    499.613605
7      0.000000
8      0.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

And we can clearly see that the `128` gets a `_zscore` of `499`.  We can safely conclude from a simple hypothesis test that the `128` is very unlikely to have come from the same distribution as the rest of the data within the group.

We can filter it like:

```
df[df.groupby('group').value.transform(_zscore) <= 3]

  group    value
0     a    2.000
1     b  123.000
2     c    4.000
3     a    2.300
4     a    2.500
5     b  127.000
7     c    4.000
8     c    0.003
```