# Drop Values from Pandas Dataframe Groups of a Column keeping 1 STD from mean of Groups

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group, describe

on a Pandas df I want to drop rows on a column when its individual value is more or less 1 std from the mean of the group.

For instance, I have a list of names related to an state, and I want to drop every instance that is above or below 1 std of price of the state.

thx.

```
#df
state price
a       10
a       30
a       60
b       60
b       50
...
n       x


stats = df.groupby('state')['price'].describe()
```

edit: thanks @MYousefi

but look my output, i still can see outliers on the second graph

[Ans1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24zn.png)

Edit2: problem solved with @MYousefi link below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to calculate the deviation from the mean and select.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10], ['a', 30], ['a', 60], ['b', 10], ['b', 50], ['b', 60]], columns = ['state', 'price'])

agg = df.groupby('state')['price'].agg(['mean', 'std'])

df[((df[['state', 'price']].set_index('state')['price'] - agg['mean']).abs() / agg['std']).reset_index(drop=True) <= 1]
```

The output of the last statement should be:

```
  state  price
0     a     10
1     a     30
4     b     50
5     b     60
```

Also found [Pandas filter anomalies per group by Zscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243384/pandas-filter-anomalies-per-group-by-zscore) which is the same thing I believe.

Comment: Sorry, one question is that two ways? +1 std and - std, i dont quite get if `df[((df[['state', 'price']].set_index('state')['price'] - agg['mean']).abs() / agg['std']).reset_index(drop=True) <= 1]` is - 1 std

Comment: I mean, its not removing the upper outlier, i think, also my df already has an index, shoud that be a problem?. Thanks!

Comment: Abs makes it so that it'll do both positive and negative side. Also, index of the `df` should not matter.

Comment: As you can see in the example both `['a',  60]` and `['b', 10]` which are more than +-1 std from the mean.

Comment: thank you again @MYousefi, please be so kind to look at this pic. the second graph is still showing outliers. any idea? https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24zn.png

Comment: there is something odd because its not removing some random outliers.

Comment: Have you also tried the other solution from the link? It does the same thing. Does your results look odd still?

Comment: thx, solved with the link idk with your code did not work. thanks for all!